# Add recursive command to set sub directory permissions in C#

Tags: c#, recursion

I would like to add a recursive command to this script that allows it to loop through a current direcotries sub directory/files and set the permissions on the subfolders/files to whatever I would like. Here is what I have so far which allows for the permissions to be changed on the first set of subdirectories. Obviously, I can add the samecode in to keep diving down through the folder structure, but not every root folder will have the same amount of sub folders within it. I want to add the recursive command to loop through all subdirectories and when there are no more, move on to the next root folder.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Management;
using System.Management.Instrumentation;

namespace ApplyPermissions
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void selectDirectoryBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog myFolderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            myFolderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();
            selectedDirBox.Text = myFolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath.ToString();

            try
            {
                DirectoryInfo myDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(selectedDirBox.Text);
                foreach (DirectoryInfo currentDir in myDirectoryInfo.GetDirectories())
                {

                    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = currentDir.Name;
                    DirectorySecurity DirSecurity = currentDir.GetAccessControl();
                    DirSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(“Whatever permissions group I choose”, FileSystemRights.CreateFiles, AccessControlType.Allow));                
                    currentDir.SetAccessControl(DirSecurity);

                    // Step thru each file within current Directory and assign access
                    foreach (FileInfo currentFile in currentDir.GetFiles())
                    {
                        FileSecurity fileSecurity = currentFile.GetAccessControl();
                        fileSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Whatever permissions group I choose", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
                        currentFile.SetAccessControl(fileSecurity);
                    }

                    foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in currentDir.GetDirectories ())
                    {


                        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = currentDir.Name + "/" + subDir.Name;
                        DirectorySecurity allsubDirSecurity = subDir.GetAccessControl();
                        allsubDirSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Whatever permissions group I choose ", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
                        subDir.SetAccessControl(allsubDirSecurity);

                        // Step thru each file within current SubDirectory and assign access
                        foreach (FileInfo currentFile in subDir.GetFiles())
                        {
                            FileSecurity fileSecurity = currentFile.GetAccessControl();
                            fileSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Whatever permissions group I choose", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
                            currentFile.SetAccessControl(fileSecurity);
                        }
                    }
                }

                labelFinished.Text = "Completed Successfully";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "/////////////////" + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if your target framework is 4.0, recommend that you use the Directory.EnumerateFiles method (you can also find 3rd code that does the same thing.)

Assuming this is a no-go, you can simplify your recursive processing by using the yield keyword, e.g. make a traverse method based on yield -- I'm showing this with a filter function to since it would often be useful in directory traversal ad should give you ideas.

```
static IEnumerable<string> traverse(string path, Func<string, bool> filter)
{
    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(path).Where(filter))
    {
        yield return f;
    }

    foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
    {
        foreach (string f in traverse(d, filter))
        {
            yield return f;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you use traversal() this way

```
var files = traverse(PATH, WHERE);
foreach (string f in files) { DoWhatever; }
```

You will have a more easily reusable directory traversal at your fingertips. I know that I am not yielding directories in the snippet above, but if I wanted to process both files and directory, I would base this on the DirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos method instead.

I forget when the yield feature was added, but it has been available for quite a while.